# Instantiate view controller from Storyboard with a descendant class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have a generic view controller in my Storyboard, let's say it's class set to `MyController` class. I also have a view controller class (`MySubControllerA`) which inherits from `MyController`:

```
@interface MySubControllerA <MyController>
...
@end
```

The descendant class is used to overwrite some functions in the parent class.

I can instantiate the main class with this:

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];
```

But of course this will be instantiated in the class which is given in the Storyboard for the "MyController" identifier.

I want to have an instance of `MySubControllerA` which accesses everything which was set in the Storyboard and still has it's own functions. Is this possible somehow? Maybe it is not the proper way to solve this problem. Is there a better way to do this? I really don't want to mess `MyController` with the specific code which I belongs to `MySubControllerA`.

Comment: The storyboard is going to instantiate whatever class your controller is set to, so you should set the controller in the storyboard to be a MySubControllerA. It will still inherit what it needs from MyController.

Comment: I want to instantiate the same Storyboard object as multiple subclasses.

Comment: Well, what you want, and what is possible are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common feature request for storyboards, but unfortunately isn't possible at this point.  I can tell you from weeks of first hand experience that if you try and hack a way to make this work, you will regret it.

Comment: If this is a common pattern, how would you solve it?

Comment: haha - oh man.  #truth.  I've tried doing the same for awhile myself.  This is something a lot of us are trying to do, but it's not currently possible.  This is a feature request for Apple, maybe with the next version of Xcode.

Comment: @gklka It's a common feature request, not a common pattern.  The closest you can do is be clever about delegates and data sources or reusable cells that support different layouts.  At the end of the day, you just have to accept the duplication of effort at this point in time.